# Referencing a new document created in Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

When I add a new document how can I reference the newly created document's data property?

For example:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
let addDoc = db.collection('cities').add({
  name: 'Tokyo',
  country: 'Japan'
}).then(ref => {
  console.log('Added document with ID: ', ref.id);
  console.log(ref.data()); // << Errors!
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to access the data this way? You have it: {name: 'Tokyo', country: 'Japan'}

Comment: In this specific case, the data of the document will be exactly the same as the object you already passed to `add()`.  You can just store a reference to that object instead of trying to read it again.  Are you expecting something different?  If so, could you explain what you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Ref is just a pointer to a database location of type [*firebase.firestore.DocumentReference*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#id), which doesn't have the data() method. You can do something like this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});

const db = admin.firestore();

let data = {
  name: 'Tokyo',
  country: 'Japan'
};

//Adding data (name: 'Tokyo', country: 'Japan')
let setDoc = db.collection('cities').add(data).then(ref => {
  console.log('Added document with ID: ', ref.id);

  // Retrieving the data from the recently created document.
  return db.collection('cities').doc(ref.id).get()
        .then(doc => {
           if (!doc.exists) {
             console.log('No such document!');
           } else {
             console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
           }
        })
       .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error getting document', err);
       });

}).catch(err => {
 console.log('Error adding the data',err);
});
```

You will retrieve `Document data: { name: 'Tokyo', country: 'Japan' }`, which is the same data that you just added above.